# Get latest mail using CFIMAP in coldfusion

Tags: java, coldfusion, imap, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-10

I am trying to get latest mail using `cfimap` like this:

```
<cfset local.objIMAP = structNew()>
<cfset local.objIMAP.server = "imap.gmail.com">
<cfset local.objIMAP.username = "username">
<cfset local.objIMAP.password = "password">

<!--- Open the connection --->
<cfimap 
    action="open" 
    secure="yes" 
    connection="myConnection"
    attributeCollection="#local.objIMAP#">  

<cfimap 
  action="getHeaderOnly" 
  connection="myConnection" 
  name="getHeaders">

<!--- Get the messagenumber of latest mail --->
<cfquery dbtype="query" name="getID">
   SELECT MAX(getHeaders.messagenumber) AS latestMessage
   FROM getHeaders
</cfquery>
<cfimap 
  action="getall" 
  connection="myConnection" 
  name="getAttachment"  
  attachmentpath="E:/"
  MessageNumber="#getID.latestMessage#">
```

I am getting timeouts in case where number of mails are more.

So is there other way to get the latest mail?

Or using `java` can we get the `UID` or `messageNumber` of the latest mail in lesser time?

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you may need to update the read messages to "read" like:

```
<cfimap action="MarkRead" connection = "Conn" messagenumber="#getHeaders.messagenumber#">
```

after the message id done with work.

so you can query the latest messages as:

```
<cfquery dbtype="query" name="getMails">
  select * from getHeaders 
  where seen=<cfqueryparam value="no" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"> 
 </cfquery>
```

also you can filter with received date

you can refer http://shemy-coldfusion.blogspot.in/2013/03/coldfusion-code-to-get-multiple-mail.html

Comment: I don't think marking them read is going to solve the problem. In case of more mails, the time to get `headers` or `all` will be more.

Comment: mark them as read and move to some other folder  <cfimap action="movemail" connection = "Conn"  newfolder="Read mails" uid="#getHeaders.messagenumber#">